# Relative position move left causing content to stay right

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get rid of the gap caused when moving a left-floated div to the left by using negative offset.

Site in question:

http://www.imvu-e.com/services/hov/index_wip.php?avatar22=191;741328;2145830;3414888;4683846;5542063;6041125;6698072;8508954;11856954;13682868;14965631;20383310;21560759;22275311;22351471;22697202;25083685;30621584;30678733;31548266

The pic class

```
.pic {
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    height: 750px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    position: relative;
    left: -191px;
}
```

This is how I am moving the picture to the left, and I want the content on the right (Clothes, Avatar & Skin, and Head & Face) to be left aligned; similar to how accessories is positioned.

I want to avoid just moving them to the left using the same process.

Comment: Please post it as fiddle so we can work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi now define your **id** `#avatar_products` `position: relative;` and your class 
`.pic`    `position: absolute;left: -192px;`

as like this

```
#avatar_products{position: relative;}
.pic{    position: absolute;left: -192px;}
```

than result is this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because your website is not responsive and doesn't resize/move, you can position the pic/guy absolute which removes the element from the pages flow and fixes your problem.

CSS:

```
.pic {
    float: left;
    height: 750px;
    left: 497px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 175px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just replace your div having the class pic from the current place and put just under the menu. Then **remove the left property from the class pic and also change the position to absoute**. After that you just adjust the top position only.